# issue with jquery and settimeout function , showing popup block on browser

Tags: jquery, popup, settimeout, blocking, simplemodal

I want to submit Form using jquery on new tab with messgae on parent screen. Actually Form should submit on new page after 10 sec (we will show wait message on screen). but it is showing popup blocker on page while running below code

here is sample code

```
  jQuery(".submit-quotecriteria a").attr('class', 'getaquotebutton1');
  jQuery('.submit-quotecriteria .getaquotebutton1').click(function()
  {           

    var t=setTimeout(function(){processend(); },10000);   
  });
  function processend()
  {
      jQuery.fn.modalBox("close"); 
      jQuery("#quotecriteria_form").submit();
      return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('.submit-quotecriteria a').addClass('getaquotebutton1')
.on("click", function()
{           
  var t = setTimeout(function()
  {
    processend();
  }, 10000);
});

function processend()
{
  jQuery.fn.modalBox('close');
  jQuery('#quotecriteria_form').submit();
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Next time don't just post your code here, give a brief explanation it will help income users understand better your answer.